# Why is the element displayed on hover not showing in nested CSS drop downs?

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, html-table

I am trying to get get a nested CSS drop down to work. The information in the menus is generated using the results from a database. The first drop down works fine; it is just when I hover on the rows nothing happens.

Can anyone see where I am going wrong? My understanding is that when I hover over a table row (i.e. `<tr>`) with the class name of *test* it should then show the element with class name *dropcontent2* to the right of this, but it is not working ><.

Below is an image of what I am getting at the moment -     the "test" text I am trying to display to the right of row I hover on, however it just shows even though the **display** property is set to *none*.

[image: screenshot of current state]

#### Starting PHP:

```
if (!empty($result))
  {
            echo "<div class='dropdown'>";
              echo "<span class='label label-success'>Domain Found In History</span>";
                echo " <div class='dropdown-content'>";
                    $this_database->displaySearchResults($result);
                  echo "</div>";
              echo "</div>";
  }
```

#### PHP function called above:

```
  function displaySearchResults($idArray)
{
  $servername = $this->servername;
  $username = $this->username;
  $password = $this->password;
  $dbname = $this->dbname;
  #Opens the MYSQL Connection
  $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if (!$conn)
    {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    ## Begining of formatting of drop down table
    echo "<table class='table table-condensed'>";
     echo "<tr>";
      echo "<th>Date</th>";
        echo "<th>Time</th>";
          echo "</tr>";
          ##Loops through all the matching ID's
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($idArray); $i++)
    {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM dns WHERE id LIKE '$idArray[$i]' ");
          $stmt->bind_param($idArray[$i]);
            $stmt->execute();
              $result = $stmt->get_result();
              ## For ever matching ID it prints out the date/time into the drop down table
              while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
              {
                echo "<tr class='test'>";
                  echo "<td>".$row["date"]."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row["time"]."</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                      echo "<div class='drop2content'>";
                        echo "<tr>";
                          echo "<td>Test </td>";
                              echo "</tr>";
                                echo "</div>";

              }
  }
              echo "</table>";
}
```

#### CSS

```
 /* Show History Drop down Styling */

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown
{
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content
{
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 1;
   margin-top:2%;
   background-color:white;
}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content
{
   display: block;
}

.drop2content
{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  background-color:white;
}

.test:hover .drop2content
{
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  left:100%;
  top:0%;

}
.test > td
 {
  position:relative;
}
.test
{
  position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Try to check the php class show the expected output. Otherwise can u add some working example or put final result code after your database class execution.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of it working - http://imgur.com/a/ao7ly   What i want to happen is when I hover over the date/time it then opens another box to the right of it (Like a nested HTML/CSS drop down)  At the moment, nothing happens,.

Comment: May be your format for loading table is incorrect. Check with that. Try with this  

<table class='table table-condensed'>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
       <th>Time</th>
          </tr> 
          
          <tr class='test'>
                 <td>Today</td>
                 <td>10.10</td>
                 <table>
                      <tr class='drop2content'>
                         <td>Test </td>
                       </tr>
                 </table>  
           </tr>
            
  </table>

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have updated my question with what I have currently and I am getting - imgur.com/a/U4I3Z Closer than I was before

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply `position:relative;` to `.test`, otherwise `.drop2content` will appear off the screen.

```
.test {
  position:relative;
}
```

You might have to do the below CSS instead, depending on the result you want.

```
.test > td {
  position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Do I do this on it's own? Or within the 
.test:hover .drop2content section? tried in both ><

Comment: I have updated my answer. It now shows the CSS you need to add.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have updated my question with what I have currently and I am getting - http://imgur.com/a/U4I3Z    Closer than I was before...

Comment: You don't have to add both of those style. You will only need one them. Test them individually and see how it effects the position.

Answer (score 0):

If your results from php may be correct. this will be work. Try this, rather than add div change to table what i suggest to you before in comment.

Here example

```css
.dropdown
{
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content
{
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 1;
   margin-top:2%;
   background-color:white;
}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content
{
   display: block;
}

.drop2content
{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  background-color:white;
}

.test:hover .drop2content
{
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  left:100%;
  top:0%;

}
.test > td
 {
  position:relative;
}
.test
{
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div class='dropdown'>
<span class='label label-success'>Domain Found In History</span>
<div class='dropdown-content'>
                   100.0.0.1
</div>
 </div>
              
  <table class='table table-condensed main'>
    <tr>
     <th>Date</th>
      <th>Time</th>
    </tr>
          
     <tr class='test'>
        <td>2017/06/18</td>
        <td>7.55 pm</td>
      
        <td>
        <table class='drop2content'>
              <tr>
                   <td>Test </td>
              </tr> 
         </table>
        <td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### The main issue

The [permitted content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table#table-mdls) for a [table element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) (i.e. `<table>`) does not include [*div*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div) elements.

> **Permitted Content**  
> In this order:
>    - an optional [`<caption>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/caption) element
>    - zero or more [`<colgroup>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/colgroup) elements,
>    - an optional [`<thead>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/thead) element
>    - either one of the following: 
>           - zero or more [`<tbody>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody) elements
>        - one or more [`<tr>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr) elements
>    - an optional [`<thead>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/thead) element
>   <sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table#table-mdls)</sup>

Thus `<div class='drop2content'>` is invalid content when a direct child of  `<table class='table table-condensed'>`

#### Options:

1. Keep the table structure and convert the `<div class='drop2content'>` to a table cell (i.e. `<td>`) with the same class name. Then remove the absolute position on selector `.test:hover  .drop2content` so it is just:

   ```
   .test:hover  .drop2content {
        display: block;
   }
   ```

   See a demonstration of this in [this phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/u8es-ww71).
2. Instead of using the HTML table, use div elements with the table layout (refer to [this post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/277778/244085) for more information)).

   So add this CSS:

   ```
   .table {
       display: table;
   }
   .row {
       display: table-row;
   }
   .table-header, .cell {
       display: table-cell;
       padding: 2px;
   }
   ```

   Then start the table:

   ```
   echo "<div class='table table-condensed'>";
   echo "<div class='row'>";
   echo "<div class='table-header'>Date</div>";
   echo "<div>Time</div>";
   echo "</div>";
   ```

   And for each row:

   ```
   echo "<div class='row test'>";
   echo "<div class='cell'>".$row["date"]."</div>";
   echo "<div class='cell'>".$row["time"]."</div>";
   echo "<div class='drop2content'>";
   echo "<div>Test </div>";
   echo "</div>";
   echo "</div>";
   ```

   And just as in Option #1, remove the absolute position on selector `.test:hover  .drop2content` so it is just:

   ```
   .test:hover  .drop2content {
       display: block;
   }
   ```

   See it demonstrated in [this phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/2gmd-rdzr).

**Disclaimer**: The database results in the phpfiddle examples are simulated using sample classes that mock database queries, since there is not really a database connection available for phpFiddle that I have access to.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table#table-mdls</sub>